# Django Static Inlines

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

I have a model `Student` with lots of fields and a model `Document` with a `ForeignKey` to `Student`. I'm using an inline to edit `Student`s' associated `Document`s.

models.py:

```
class Document(models.Model):

    def media_path(instance, filename):
        return '{0}/{1}'.format(instance.Student.Id, filename)

    File = models.FileField(
        _('File'),
        upload_to=media_path,)

    Title = models.CharField(
        _('File Name'),
        max_length=32,
        blank=True,)

    Student = models.ForeignKey(
        Student,
        null=True,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _('Document')
        verbose_name_plural = _('Documents')
```

admin.py:

```
class DocumentInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Document
    extra = 0


class StudentAdmin(UserAdmin):
    ...
    inlines = [
        DocumentInline,
    ]

    class Meta:
        model = Student


admin.site.register(Student, StudentAdmin)
```

What I want is to add 3 inline `Document` lines with specific `Title` each time a `Student` is created, so for example:

I just created a `Student` and I already have 3 lines in the `Document` inlines section and each one with a pre-defined `Title` (and the `File` obviously is empty):

- File 1
- File 2
- File 3

How can I do such thing?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You could add a receiver to intercept the post save signal:

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver

@receiver(post_save, sender=Student)
def create_default_docs(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        for title in ['title1','title2','title3']:
            d = Document(title=title, student=instance)
            d.save()
```

This code gets executed after the student model has been saved. If the model has just been created, it will then create the three documents with the default titles specified.

One thing to note, you'd need to allow your file field to allow nulls, as at the moment it's a required field.

Comment: Sorry for the dumb question, I just have never used signals, where should I put this code?

Comment: No worries. You can just add this to your models.py file

Comment: Doesn't seem to work. I tried to create a `Student` in my admin and there were no changes in the inline `Document`s section.

Comment: Have any documents been created?

Comment: I've just realised that your attributes start with a capital letter, so I assume that you updated to ```Document(Title=title, Student=instance)```?

Comment: Nope. BTW, I've set the `extra` to be 0, but I tried to change to change it to 4 and just 4 empty `Document`s have bean created.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127552/discussion-between-tdsymonds-and-android).